# accessing flash messenger not from a controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm writing a PHP application using zend framework 2.2.2.

I would like to know how to be able to use the FlashMessanger using zend framework 2.

now I know that it's possible to fetch the Flash Messanger using zf1 using the following code:

```
        $this->messenger = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('flashMessenger');
```

how it is possible to fetch the flash messenger using zf2 ?

the thing is that I want to the flash messenger to be available in my own utility class
so I don't have the controller available to fetch the messenger from there.

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FlashMessenger is a ControllerPlugin [`Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\FlashMessenger`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-flashmessenger) and that's where it makes the most sense of using it. Injecting the Messenger into your "UtilityClasses" to me sounds like a somewhat bad idea, since this would make the response-checking so much more complicated and the controllers quite more bloated. So take that in mind.

However it is possible to get the `FlashMessenger` into any class you want. The only catch is, all the classes you want the FM to be available at, have to be called by the ServiceManager. Your ServiceFactories then would look like this:

```
// Module#getServiceConfig() 
return array('factories' => array(
    'MyServiceClass' => function($serviceLocator) {
        return new MyService(
            $serviceLocator->get('controllerpluginmanager')->get('flashmessenger')
        );
    }
));
```

Of course you could re-write it to use setter-injection or even lazy-getters in your ServiceClass if you wish you inject the full `ServiceLocator` (which isn't advised).